# Invalid(Google Directions API)

Tags: android, http, httprequest, directions

Why is my HTTP request to the Google Directions API invalid?

Below, is the URL of my HTTP request:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(50.8441144,-0.1094412)&desination=(50.861796,-0.083256)&region=uk&sensor=false
```

The JSON response is as follows:

```
{
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Google Directions API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled destination and may have encoded your coordinates incorrectly.  Try:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=50.8441144,-0.1094412&destination=50.861796,-0.083256&region=uk&sensor=false`

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the request url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(50.8441144,-0.1094412)&desination=(50.861796,-0.083256)&region=uk&sensor=false
```

Should be:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(50.8441144,-0.1094412)&destination=(50.861796,-0.083256)&region=uk&sensor=false
```

Note: des**t**ination.